# how to populate the crystal reports from multiple tables using linq to entity

Tags: linq-to-entities

i have done the single table crystal report. now i want to display the multiple table data in crystal reports but it gives me exception "DataSet does not support System.Nullable<>."
kindly guide me to solve this problem, or give me other solution for it. 
the Code is

ReportDocument report = new ReportDocument();

```
        report.Load(Server.MapPath("Assets.rpt"));
        using (var matr = new InventoryDBEntities())
        {
            report.SetDataSource(from p in matr.Issueds
                                select new
                                 {
                                     SerialNo = p.SerialNo,
                                     FixedAssetNO = matr.Items.Where(b => b.SerialNo == p.SerialNo).Select(b => b.FixedAssetNO).FirstOrDefault(),
                                     Category = matr.Items.Where(b => b.SerialNo == p.SerialNo).Select(b => b.Type).FirstOrDefault(),
                                     ModelNo = matr.Items.Where(b => b.SerialNo == p.SerialNo).Select(b => b.ModelNo).FirstOrDefault(),
                                     IssueToUser = p.IssuedPerson,
                                     IssueToDept = p.IssuedDept,
                                     UpdatedBy = matr.Emploees.Where(b => b.EID == p.EID).Select(b => b.Name).FirstOrDefault(),
                                     IssuedDate = p.IssuedDate,
                                  });

        }


            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report;
```

Comment: DataSet does not support nullable types. You may want to try using DbNull instead of null.